# InvalidCastException in returning most recently added column

Tags: c#, sql

I want to return the last column of most recently inserted record from a database table. I keep getting this error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in SchoolManagement.exe
>
> Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued

Code:

```
public int A()
{
    string _connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
    string stmt = "SELECT TOP 1 RegistrationNumber FROM tblStudentBiodata ORDER BY RegistrationNumber DESC";


    int count = 0;

    using (SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(_connection))
    {
        using(SqlCommand cmdCount = new SqlCommand(stmt, thisConnection))
        {
            thisConnection.Open();
            count = (int)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cast to int is throwing the exception:

```
count = (int)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();
```

Your conversion is not safe, and you are certainly not getting back an integer from the ExecuteScalar method. In fact, the ExecuteScalar method will return the result wrapped (boxed) into an `Object` so be aware that the object could contain any type (e.g. float, decimal, int etc.).

Also make sure you are not casting from a null value, since that would be returned if there are no records in the table. So make sure to add a check if the object is null before attempting to cast.

Per my explanation, check the type of `RegistrationNumber` column in SQL server and make sure to cast to the correct type in your C# code.

Here is a list of the type mappings between SQL Server and C#:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: the datatype for RegistrationNumber is varchar(50)

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed in another answer, below line is causing the exception and fir sure `RegistrationNumber` column is not `INT` type. I doubt it would be SQL `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` column.

```
count = (int)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();
```

In this case, instead of doing a direct casting, try casting it indirectly using `AS` operator and declare your `count` variable as `nullable Int` like

```
int? count = 0;
count = cmdCount.ExecuteScalar() as int?;
```

Then check and use it

```
if (count != null)
{
   //Do something with it
}
```